# Ввести определенный текст каждый раз после нужного слова

Tags: notepad++

Доброго времени суток.

С недавнего времени пришлось осваивать Notepad++ я в этом деле далеко не мастер и буду признателен если кто-нибудь доходчиво может объяснить суть проблемы.

Есть текст в Notepad++ в нем есть строка с текстом `M03` после неё нужно создать новую строку с текстом `G4 P1000`. Сделать это нужно раз эдак 200 - 300. Я всю эту процедуру проделывал вручную. Времени занимает просто кучу. Подскажите как можно это сделать попроще. Возможно даже не в NPP.

Буду очень признателен.

Это как оно есть в начале:
[image: Это как оно есть в начале]

А вот что должно получиться:
[image: А вот что должно получиться]

Важно что сделать это нужно именно в отдельных строках.

Comment: В тегах sublime, в заголовке node++, в скринах notepad. Не надо так(

Comment: В редакторе SublimeText3 очень удобно работать с мультиселектом. Ваша задача решается выделением M03, далее cmd+ctrl+G, те выбор всех вхождений (маковский шорткат имеет эквивалент в win), стрелка вправо для сброса выделений на каретки ввода за всеми вхождениями M03, далее enter и ввод G4 P1000

Answer (score 2):

Для Windows'овских переводов строк - так. Для других - аналогично.

[image]

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшое !) Конец моим мучениям .Я Вам правда очень признателен за совет )

Comment: @СашаКовальський, в таком случае следует принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `найти и заменить`. Нажимаете `ctrl+f` --> выберите вкладку `заменить`. Дальше укажите найти - `M03`, укажите - расширенный и поставьте заменить - на `M03\nG4 P1000`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В NPP `\n` так не работает, в отличие от саблайма.

Comment: я проверил перед тем как писать. у меня поменялось как нужно.

Comment: Зависит от файла: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scEJX.png